# Oracle R_ROLE_TAB_PRIVS table?

Tags: oracle

What is the difference between this table and ROLE_TAB_PRIVS?  The later has 36 tables associated with a role, the former (R_ROLE_TAB_PRIVS) only has 18.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

One is a documented oracle supplied view, the other is not.

I get ORA-00942 "table or view does not exist" for `R_ROLE_TAB_PRIVS`. (21c ATP Free Tier)

Comment: Thanks, somebody 15+ years ago created a table in my database with that name.  Super confusing!